# Can not set a user password using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a user with a specific password using powershell.  The below code creates the user but then gives me a rejected credentials error when I attempt to search AD using this new user.  Similarly a runas command tells me the password is bad.  I have also tried the Set-ADAccountPassword cmdlet after creating the user and I get no error but I can confirm that I am not actually setting the password.  I also can not find a password reset Event when I do this.  When I use the "Users and Computers" UI, I am able to reset the password on this user properly (and I see the Event).  I am running the code on the DC as a Domain Admin with 'Run as Administrator'.

I set up a test Domain and the below code works properly so it is something screwy with my domain.  I have tried removing all password complexity requirements as a test but no luck.  Ideas on other things to check?

```
$Password="pa55Word!"
$Name="Tmp.User"
[securestring]$SecPass =  ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force

New-ADUser -Name $Name -AccountPassword $SecPass -Enabled $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Name, $SecPass
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -eq $Name' -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: Do you have more than one domain controller in that domain?

Comment: I have a child domain, but only 1 DC in the domain where I am attempting to set / create the password.

Comment: Your filter on Get-ADUser is wrong. By using single quotes, `$Name` will not be expanded. do `"Name -eq '$Name'"`

Comment: Thanks Theo, but surprisingly $Name is handled properly in the single quotes (even when the variable contains a space character)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

I ran the same script and I am able to get the user details with new user credentials

I am able to the set the password using **Set-ADAccountPassword** cmdlet

The issue might be with your domain or from the DC where you are running the script